# Jquery toggle only works when element starts visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slide toggle function on my website which used to work fine. Now (for me out of the blue) the toggle function works only if the element is visible, just normal in both ways. The blocks that start as display none don't do anything anymore. I don't have any errors in my scripts if I check with my browser development tool. What happened here?

http://venzo.co.nl/index.php?r=vacature/index

(click the plus/cross to toggle)

Someone who can help me out here?

Edit:
javascript function:

```
function toggle(target, kruis){
    $(target).slideToggle();
    if($(kruis).hasClass('heen') == false){
        $(kruis).addClass('heen');
        $(kruis).removeClass('terug');
    }else{
        $(kruis).addClass('terug');
        $(kruis).removeClass('heen');
    }
}
```

html to call the function:

```
<img src="handig/ikoons/plus2.png" 
            id="kruis5<?php echo $data->id;?>" 
            onclick="javascript:toggle('#vacatureUitklap<?php echo $data->id;?>', '#kruis5<?php echo $data->id;?>');" 
            class="uitklappen handje rotate <?php echo $heen;?>"/>
```

Comment: You'll have to post the code here, and preferably a minimal example on jsFiddle. We're not going to go to your website and start clicking stuff, and then search the entire source for the snippet we need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS you have added the important rule to:

```
 .onzichtbaar {
     display: none !important;
 }
```

remove it and it will work!

```
 .onzichtbaar {
     display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**JQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $('.expander').live('click', function () {
        $('#TableData').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h3><img src="toggle.png" class ="expander" alt="Expand"/> 
</h3>

<div style="display:none" id="TableData">Text</div>
<p class="traversing"></p>
```

> [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/e0tz7yhq/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this main.css line number 44:

```
.onzichtbaar {
  display: none;
}
```

**instead of

```
.onzichtbaar {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Here can not use !important
Visit: http://prowpexpert.com